# Jupyter and Common Lisp

Tags: ipython, common-lisp, zeromq, sbcl, jupyter

I'm trying to install [cl-jupyter](https://github.com/fredokun/cl-jupyter) (A common-lisp kernel for [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/)), and I can't make it work: when I open a new lisp notebook (or change the kernel of an existing notebook), it crashes after displaying the following messages:

```
[I 18:26:50.855 NotebookApp] Kernel started: ccba815a-9065-4fad-9d95-06f6291136d2
To load "cl-jupyter":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    cl-jupyter
; Loading "cl-jupyter"
...............

cl-jupyter: an enhanced interactive Common Lisp REPL
(Version 0.7 - Jupyter protocol v.5.0)
--> (C) 2014-2015 Frederic Peschanski (cf. LICENSE)

kernel configuration = ((hb_port . 58864) (shell_port . 37462)
                        (transport . tcp) (iopub_port . 43232)
                        (signature_scheme . hmac-sha256)     (control_port . 52184)
                        (stdin_port . 45879)
                        (key . 2ae7d65f-65f9-40d8-bfd4-21760eaec0ca)
                        (ip . 127.0.0.1))
[Hearbeat] starting...
[Heartbeat] thread started
[Heartbeat] thread started
[Kernel] Entering mainloop ...
[Shell] loop started
Argh! corrupted error depth, halting
fatal error encountered in SBCL pid 24605(tid 140737353922304):
%PRIMITIVE HALT called; the party is over.
```

#### Some details:

- `Jupyter` works fine with python (both 2x and 3x).
- `sbcl` also seems to work fine (I'm just starting with common-lisp, so I might be missing something - but I can run code, and use asdf and quicklisp).
- I installed it by running "**`python3 ./install-cl-jupyter.py`**".
- My `.sbclrc` file now contains just "`(load "~/quicklisp/setup.lisp")`".

#### System Information:

- OS: Linux 4.1.13-1-MANJARO x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Python 3.5.0
- SBCL 1.3.0
- Jupyter version 4.0.6

#### Some things I've tried:

The file `~/.ipython/kernels/lisp/kernel.json` contains:

```
{"argv": ["sbcl", "--non-interactive", "--load", "/home/myusername/lisp/systems/cl-jupyter/cl-jupyter.lisp", "/homemyusername/lisp/systems/cl-jupyter/src", "/home/myusername/lisp/systems/cl-jupyter", "{connection_file}"], "display_name": "SBCL Lisp", "language": "lisp"}
```

All the paths are correct. When I run the same code manually:

```
sbcl --non-interactive --load "/home/myusername/lisp/systems/cl-jupyter/cl-jupyter.lisp" "/homemyusername/lisp/systems/cl-jupyter/src" "/home/myusername/lisp/systems/cl-jupyter" kernel-07e04903-c562-4c67-bcc1-b68f4047d8d2.json
```

(where "kernel-07e04903-c562-4c67-bcc1-b68f4047d8d2.json" is an auto-generated file for a lisp-kernel that I saved), it "looks ok" (e.g. it runs, and waits with no errors).

I tried to do some quick debug-printing, and my best guess is that it crashes in `src/shell.lisp`, in the line

```
 (vbinds (identities sig msg buffers)  (message-recv (shell-socket shell))
```

But again, I could be wrong. Since it kinda looks like it has something to do with communication, I made sure that zeromq is updated.

I'm not sure what's next besides learning some more lisp, and then come back to properly debug the code - but I was hoping to learn it using Jupyter :)

I'd appreciate any suggestions,
Thanks.

Comment: Can you uncomment the `format` call in `message-recv` at the end of `src/message.lisp` ? If it's not printed then it's probably some issue with zeromq. You can also try to `trace` some functions, to narrow down where exactly the error occurs.

Comment: This is internal to sbcl. One of `*current-error-depth*` or `*maximum-error-depth*` is not bound or not a `realp` number. See: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/jared/Milawa/Support/sbcl/sbcl-1.0.29/src/code/toplevel.lisp (though note that this is from a different version of sbcl)

Comment: I'd guess that somehow `!COLD-INIT` isn't called: https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/32c7d2422e45a859b51a58709238a4f65a210506/src/code/cold-error.lisp#L119

Comment: This could be related to having multiple threads, as from this document I'd guess that it can happen in a multi threaded situation that `*maximum-error-depth*` is unbound: https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/c2708da2b982eefc2e72c1fe465c0bbeef193582/doc/internals-notes/threading-specials#L943

Comment: So, to be precise, I think this is some threading related bug in SBCL. I modified the version of sbcl you're using to be more precise when reporting that error, i.e. to report whether it's *really* `*maximum-error-depth*` that is unbound. Could you try to run with this modified version of sbcl, in order to confirm my guess? The code is to be found there: https://github.com/musteresel/sbcl/tree/split-error-depth-corruption-check The only modification is in `src/code/cold-error.lisp` to split the case checking for corrupted error depth (which you can test via github if you don't trust me ;) )

Comment: Thanks! I compiled the source with your modification, and the error I now get is "Argh! corrupted maximum error depth, halting". So it looks like you're right. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: By the way, the line "(format t "~S" SB-KERNEL:*MAXIMUM-ERROR-DEPTH*)" prints 10 (as expected), either if I put it in shell.lisp just before printing "loop started" or if I put it in kernel.lisp just before printing "starting...." or printing "loop started".

Comment: And " (format t "~S" (SB-INT:FIXNUMP SB-KERNEL:*MAXIMUM-ERROR-DEPTH*))" prints "T"...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This issue is caused by a change in the size of the message structure, `zmq_msg_t`, in 0MQ version 4.1.x to 64 bytes from a size of 32 bytes in version 4.0.x.

The 0MQ interface library used by `cl-jupyter` is `pzmq`, and that library is stated to support 0MQ up to version 4.0.  At the time of this writing, `pzmq` uses a 0MQ message size of 32 bytes.  This leads to internal errors if 0MQ version 4.1.x is installed.

There are two solutions here:

1. Downgrade the 0MQ installation to version 4.0.x
2. Fix the `pzmq` library by updating the definition of `msg%` in `c-api.lisp` from 32 to 64 bytes.

**Update - 9 May 2016**

The `pzmq` library was updated to support 0MQ version 4.1.x, (preserving  compatibility with older versions).  The new version of `pzmq` is planned for release as part of the May 2016 Quicklisp release.

**Update - 1 June 2016**

The May 2016 Quicklisp release includes updates to the `pzmq` library which resolve this issue.  A downgrade of 0MQ or modifications to the `pzmq` library are no longer necessary.