# How to extract data from message in C# ZeroMQ?

Tags: c#, zeromq

I need to send data from `C++` to `C#`.

On `C++` side, under Linux, I am using **`ZMQ`** library **`version 4.1.4`**.

`C#` side is using [**`clrzmq4`**](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq4/) library based on `4.1.5 version`.

So the part where I send message in `C++`:

```
char tempStr[] = "ABCD";
zmq_msg_t zmsg;
zmq_msg_init_size(&zmsg, 4);
memcpy(zmq_msg_data(&zmsg), tempStr, 4);
int rc = zmq_send(reqSocket, &zmsg, sizeof(zmsg), 0);
zmq_msg_close(&zmsg);
```

`C#` code to retrieve message:

```
ZFrame request = responder.ReceiveFrame();
byte[] reqBytes = new byte[100];
int n = request.Read(reqBytes, 0, 100);
```

The problem is that byte array is including all 64 bytes of **`zmq_msg_t`**. The actual data is starting from offset 16.

**`Question`** - how to properly extract data in this case? Extracting by hard coding the offset in my code is simply ugly, because one day `zmq_msg_t` may be changed from sender side and data will be located somewhere else. Other option is to avoid using `zmq_msg_t`, when both sides are not using same platform/framework. In the `clrzmq4` framework I can see there are delegates for `zmq_msg_t` types, but not sure how to use them and whether they intended for public usage.

Comment: What is in the first 15 bytes? If it is a header, perhaps it has the offset to data encoded there. If not, you'll have no choice but to hard code the offset.

Comment: Looking in C++ code, first 8 byte is `int64_t file_desc` and other 8 byte is `metadata_t *metadata` inside struct. Then comes data. I was hoping that someone with knowledge of clrzmq4 library may give hint how to handle it. Or perhaps recommend other .NET framework which has data extraction routines.

Comment: Be carefull on how multipart messages are being assembled in ZeroMQ. As explained in your other post, if not developing intentionally on a low-level, avoid to use the zmq_msg_t directly and use the higher-level API interface.

Comment: Also may have noticed Steve Balousek's reminder about **changed 32B -> 64B `zmq_msg_t` sizing, since version 4.1.x**, so non-homogeneous deliveries shall operate on high-level services, not byte-scale/alignment **details >>> http://stackoverflow.com/a/37107166/3666197**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mixing the send types on the c++ side, if using zmq_msg_t you dont need the variant with a size, thats for sending a buffer.

If using the buffer function

```
int zmq_send (void *socket, void *buf, size_t len, int flags)
```

Then you should do

```
zmq_send(reqSocket, tempStr, 4, 0);
```

However if using `zmq_msg_t` variant

```
int zmq_msg_send (zmq_msg_t *msg, void *socket, int flags)
```

Then you should do :

```
zmq_msg_send (&zmsg, reqSocket, 0);
```