# When I should use zmq_msg_t?

Tags: c++, zeromq

The functions for sending and receiving messages as follows:

```
int zmq_send (void *socket, void *buf, size_t len, int flags);
int zmq_recv (void *socket, void *buf, size_t len, int flags);
```

However, from documentation it's not clear when I have to use `zmq_msg_t` or my custom data directly. So in which cases I should consider using `zmq_msg_t` and in which case send my data directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those functions will construct a `zmq_msg_t`internally then use the `zmq_msg_t` variant of the function. This is convenient but if you want to send the same message multiple times it would be more efficient (less copying) to create a `zmq_msg_t` and use those variants.

Comment: Yes, in case there is some remarkable amount of re-use of the once initialised structure, there is a reason to go this way. [+1 to David]

Comment: It's strange, because if I don't use `zmq_msg_t` to send message through `zmq_send`, then on receiving endpoint I am not getting `zmq_msg_t`'s internal data structure. If using it, I am getting 16 byte internal data at the beginning, which is useless for my receiving application.

Comment: How is the data you're trying to sending formatted? (what data types etc?)

Comment: My other post have that all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397992/how-to-extract-data-from-message-in-c-sharp-zeromq

Comment: If internally it wraps my data into `zmq_msg_t`, then it appears I just don't have to wrap myself anymore and that will solve also the original question to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

### Never TLDR

Be rather careful on how to setup, load/unload and consume/destroy the supporting low-level data structures that the cool and powerful **`ZeroMQ`**-library services rely on.

Otherwise, one has better to rather use the high-level companion functions.

---

### Do not hesitate to read The Book - worth one's time

Pieter HINTJENS recommends in page 42, item 4:

> To release (not destroy) a message, you call **`zmq_msg_close()`**. This drops a reference, and eventually 0MQ will destroy the message.

In [API documentation](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-msg-close) you may find even stronger caution:

```
The zmq_msg_close() function shall inform the ØMQ infrastructure
that any resources associated with the message object
referenced by msg are no longer required and may be released.

Actual release of resources associated with the message object
shall be postponed by ØMQ until all users of the message or underlying
data buffer have indicated it is no longer required.

Applications should ensure that zmq_msg_close() is called
once a message is no longer required, otherwise memory leaks may occur.
```

**Never access `zmq_msg_t` members directly,** instead always use the `zmq_msg` family of functions.

```
Return value:
              zmq_msg_close() function shall return zero if successful.
                              Otherwise it shall return -1 and
                              set errno to one of the values defined below.
Errors
              EFAULT          Invalid message.
```